# Android - Spinner Tree

Tags: java, android, tree, spinner

I'm trying to display a tree into a spinner. I know what I want is not easy at all, but I'm sure that it is possible.

Here is what I have:

[image]

And here is what I'd like to have: http://crepitus.com/misc/ext/tree.html

So, how can I do that? Where to start?

I hope you'll can help me.

Thanks.

Regards.

V.

Comment: You should start by looking on ExpandableListView, and adding a checkBox in each inflated view. You can look at my question to see basically how i did : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5979947/android-compatibility-between-expandablelistview-and-checktextview-checkbox

Comment: I tried something but that's very difficult because I have 5 depth levels. Here is a link that looks good: http://img.androidsoftware.us/apk/img8/201108101457578628.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this :
http://code.google.com/p/tree-view-list-android/

It should be what you want.